# UWP binding asynchronously loaded data

Tags: c#, events, uwp, binding, viewmodel

I have 2 pages, when I navigate from the first one to the other, I send it an id (in NavigationEvent). Then I call a function on its ViewModel with the id passed and which loads an object to the ViewModel's property asynchronously by a service. I binded the properties of the object in my view and try to call PropertyChanged.Invoke in the getters of the object, but it's always null. How can I bind my view to this obejct?

The data class I want to bind:

```
class Dog: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _name;

    public int Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name= value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Dog Dog{ get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Dog = new Dog();
    }

    public async void LoadDog(string id)
    {
        var service = newvDogService();
        Dog = await service.GetDogAsync(id);
    }
}
```

The view:

```
public sealed partial class DogPage : Page
{
    private string dogId { get; set; }

    public DogPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        dogId = e.Parameter.ToString();

        ViewModel.LoadDog(dogId);
    }
}
```

In the xaml file:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MyViewModel x:Name ="ViewModel"/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

...

```
 Text="{Binding Dog.Name}"
```

Comment: It is best when going to a second page to create a new webpage so you have both the the first page and second page.  When you navigate away from the first page you loose objects.  You also do not have to navigate back to the original page since you never left the page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could simplify the binding process. For an object binding, you don’t need to use the ViewModel. When you pass the id in NavigationEvent, you could get the new Dog object directly via the id. At first, you could create a Dog object that Name property is null. Then you could change the previous object Name through the newly created object.

Please refer to the following code.

Xaml code:

```
  <StackPanel DataContext="{x:Bind Dog,Mode=OneWay}">         
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name,Mode=OneWay}"/>
  </StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
       
        public Dog Dog { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            Dog = new Dog { Name = "" };
        }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
     {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        dogId = e.Parameter.ToString();
        var dog = await service.GetDogAsync(dogId);
Dog.Name=dog.Name;
    }
       
}

public class Dog : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```